# Polar decompostion for the operator algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I find that most of books discussing the polar decompostion at the W*-algebras, but not C*-algebras. I guess the rough reason is that the element of W*algebras has the well supported set, but I want to know more details.

1) What is the basic difference between the C*-algebras and W*-algebras such that the W*-algebras has the well supported set.

2) If we insist to do the polar decompostion for a noninvertible element in the C*-algebras, what will happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by the "well supported set", but in any case; C*-algebras are not closed under the polar decomposition of non-invertible elements. For this you have to go to the enveloping von Neumann (W*-) algebra.  This is essentially because von Neumann algebras are closed under the Borel functional calculus, whereas C*-algebras are only closed under the continuous functional calculus.  On the other hand, a (unital) C*-algebra is closed under the polar decomposition of its invertible elements.  This is easy to see using the continuous functional calculus.

For example, consider the identity map $f : [-1,1]\to [-1,1]$ as a member of the C*-algebra $C[-1,1]$.  It's easy to see that if $f = |f| v$ is the polar decomposition of $f$ (i.e. $v$ is a partial isometry), then $v$ must take the values $-1$ on $[-1,0)$ and $+1$ on $(0,1]$.  You can find such a $v$ in $L^\infty[-1,1]$ but not $C[-1,1]$.

Comment: Oh, the "well supported set" is called "support" in the common operator algebra books, maybe I should choose the exact word. The point of functional calculus is a reason, but why do von Neumann algebras be closed under the Borel functional calculus? I think it comes from the von Neumann double commutation theorem which also can explain the support problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be relevant for 2):

http://www.theta.ro/jot/archive/1987-017-002/1987-017-002-014.pdf

Since, this answer is two short to be submitted, I would just add redundantly as and answer to 1) that a C*-algebra doesn't have sufficiently many projections and that the proof that a von Neumann algebra does have enough is indeed the consequence of the double commutant theorem.
cf. also the algebraic proof of the polar decomposition [Detail in the algebraic proof of the polar decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632521/detail-in-the-algebraic-proof-of-the-polar-decomposition)